# python http server receive http post and make the client redirect to another page?

Tags: python, wordpress

I am running a simple http server on a vps.

And i also have a site hosted on wordpress hosting
the wordpress website sends an http post request upon form submission , post request contains all the form fields  that user enters
the request is received by the server and the response is sent to the sender browser.

what i wanna know is : if its possible to redirect the user while sending the response ?

**i mean:**
user click on submit---->server performs required task on the received data------> **send response in such a way that user is redirected to the page on wordpress site**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HTTP_REDIRECT status code.

{'statusCode': 301, 'headers': {'Location': 'https://google.com'}

Returning 301 the browser will redirect to the Location (google.com)

Hope it helps!